# java.lang.IllegalStateException thrown while setSessionToken in TokenHelper

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, interceptor, httpsession

I have a Java application running on Linux OS with Jetty server.

Struts action which changes the date and time of Linux System and after it renders another page.
An action is performed successfully but while rendering the page it will throw `java.lang.IllegalStateException`.

I have used `s:token` tag in that JSP page for preventing double submissions of form.

**Error Trace is as below:**

```
ERROR TokenHelper Error creating HttpSession due response is committed to client. You can use the CreateSessionInterceptor or create the HttpSession from your action before the result is rendered to the client: null
 java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.AbstractSession.checkValid(AbstractSession.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashedSession.checkValid(HashedSession.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.AbstractSession.getAttribute(AbstractSession.java:132)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.SessionMap.get(SessionMap.java:161)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.SessionMap.put(SessionMap.java:179)
    at org.apache.struts2.util.TokenHelper.setSessionToken(TokenHelper.java:93)
    at org.apache.struts2.util.TokenHelper.setToken(TokenHelper.java:79)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.Token.buildToken(Token.java:107)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.Token.evaluateExtraParams(Token.java:97)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.evaluateParams(UIBean.java:886)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.end(UIBean.java:535)
    at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doEndTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:42)
    at org.apache.jsp.pages.Continue_jsp._jspx_meth_s_token_0(org.apache.jsp.pages.Continue_jsp:495)
    at org.apache.jsp.pages.Continue_jsp._jspx_meth_s_form_0(org.apache.jsp.pages.Continue_jsp:429)
    at org.apache.jsp.pages.Continue_jsp.access$6(org.apache.jsp.pages.Continue_jsp:407)
    at org.apache.jsp.pages.Continue_jsp$Continue_jspHelper.invoke2(org.apache.jsp.pages.Continue_jsp:1197)
    at org.apache.jsp.pages.Continue_jsp$Continue_jspHelper.invoke(org.apache.jsp.pages.Continue_jsp:1221)
```

Please let us know possible solution or suggestions to handle the error.

Comment: Post some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ERROR `TokenHelper` Error creating `HttpSession` due response is committed to client. You can use the [`CreateSessionInterceptor` class](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/CreateSessionInterceptor.html) or create the `HttpSession` from your action before the result is rendered to the client.

You can create `HttpSession` with the code similar to

```
ActionContext context = ActionContext.getContext();
SessionMap<String, T> sessionMap = (SessionMap<String, T>) context.getSession();

if (sessionMap == null) {
    sessionMap = new SessionMap<String, T>(ServletActionContext.getRequest());
    context.setSession((Map<String, Object>) sessionMap);
}
```

---

There's [`createSession` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/create-session-interceptor.html).

> This interceptor creates the `HttpSession` if it doesn't exist, also `SessionMap` is recreated and put in `ServletActionContext`.
>
> This is particular useful when using the `<@s.token>` tag in freemarker
> templates. The tag do require that a `HttpSession` is already created
> since freemarker commits the response to the client immediately.