# Null pointer exception while using tokenSession interceptor in struts2 framework

Tags: struts2, token

I am using struts2 framework . when I submit a form it gets stored in database successfully and I redirect the user to the same page but when I refresh that page again I get below error.

I am using tokenSession interceptor.

Can someone please help how to get rid of this problem?

```
Error 500--Internal Server Error
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl$SessionHelper.initSessionInfo(ServletRequestImpl.java:3193)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl$SessionHelper._getSessionInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:2894)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl$SessionHelper.getSessionInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:2881)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl$SessionHelper.getSession(ServletRequestImpl.java:2871)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.getSession(ServletRequestImpl.java:1525)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.include(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:508)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:161)
    at org.apache.struts2.result.ServletDispatcherResult.doExecute(ServletDispatcherResult.java:132)
    at org.apache.struts2.result.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:206)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.TokenSessionStoreInterceptor.handleInvalidToken(TokenSessionStoreInterceptor.java:143)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.TokenSessionStoreInterceptor.handleToken(TokenSessionStoreInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.TokenInterceptor.doIntercept(TokenInterceptor.java:139)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:99)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.factory.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:48)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:574)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:79)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:141)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3701)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3667)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2443)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2291)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2269)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1703)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1663)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:272)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:644)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)
```

Is this an issue with weblogic version?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow. It would be more helpful if you could provide more information and your code that's throwing the exception.

Comment: May be this answer can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/45104220/573032.

Comment: @YamaçKurtuluş I have added <s:token /> inside form tag and made an entry of tokenSession and defaultStack interceptors in struts.xml file . form submission works fine for the first time but after refreshing I am getting above exception. Without tokensession form submission works fine but on refreshing double submission occurs.

Comment: @RomanC thanks for your reply but that did not help much

Comment: @Pawan Why it didn't help, may be you can't get it from there?

Comment: @RomanC yes I didn't get from there since it is a kind of session problem which can not be understood from code. It is a kind of internal error with session initialisation.

Comment: I don't understand your problem well. Why and how did you use the token session intetceptor?

Comment: I am using a form when I submit it values are getting stored in database and again if I refresh the same page the same form resubmits the same values again which makes duplicate entry in table. What I have studied about token session interceptor that if it finds same token from jsp page in subsequent requests then it will reject the request and render the same output as it rendered in the previous request . I have made an entry of tokenSession interceptor in action tag and token tag in jsp within the form tag.